# Recording Phone Number and Full Name in Project Datasource

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-app-maker

I have implemented a user picker into my app in google app maker and synced up the Directory. It works when I use it and stores the email address into the Project datasource I have setup, but I also want to record the associated PrimaryPhone and FullName of the email address as seperate variables within my project database. I do not know if this will be code within a script or within the datasource onCreate or onLoad. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about security and data consistency, then you can go with server side implementation:

```js
// onCreate model event handler (takes about-to-create record as parameter)
var query = app.models.Directory.newQuery();

// assuming that email field value is populated by UserPicker widget on client-side
query.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = record.Email;
var people = query.run();

if (people.length === 1) {
  var person = people[0];

  record.FullName = person.FullName;
  record.PrimaryPhone = person.PrimaryPhone;
} else {
  // TODO: handle edge cases
}
```

If you are not paranoiac about security, you can:

1. Configure UserPicker to select entire object (check 'valueIsRecord' property checkbox).
2. Handle onValueEdit UserPicker widget event:

```js
// onValueEdit UserPicker event
// assuming that widget is bound to datasource's create mode item
var draft = widget.datasource.item;

draft.Email = newValue.PrimaryEmail;
draft.FullName = newValue.FullName;
draft.PrimaryPhone = newValue.PrimaryPhone;
```

Comment: Thank you so much I used the server side implementation. Works great!